# Bugzilla displays browser data in the comments box after I submit a bug

Tags: bugzilla

I have recently been editing my bugzilla templates to create customised default text for comments boxes etc. Now when I commit a bug it seems to automatically add the browser details at the start of the comment in the edit page (comments section under the additional comments box). For example if I add the comment "Submitted by A.N. Other, bug needs to be fixed"

The text in the comment list on the edit_bug page will read:

"User-Agent:       Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US)
AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.126 Safari/533.4
Build Identifier:

Submitted by A.N. Other, bug needs to be fixed

Reproducible:

Steps to reproduce"

The extra text seems to be coming from comment-guided.txt.tmpl, I have checked comment.txt.tmpl and this still seems to have its original values. Does anyone have any suggestions as to whats causing this text to show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found the problem. The follwing code seems to have crept in to the form in create.html.tmpl:

```
<input type="hidden" name="format" value="guided">
```

I have commented this out and seems to be working fine now